# Get values from clr-dropdown

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, vmware-clarity

I'm new working with angular and the clarity project, basically i have this dropdown

```
<clr-dropdown>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" clrDropdownTrigger>
                Is Active
                <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
            </button>
            <clr-dropdown-menu *clrIfOpen>
                <div clrDropdownItem>Item1</div>
                <div clrDropdownItem>Item2</div>
            </clr-dropdown-menu>
</clr-dropdown>
<br>None Selected
```

And I don't know how to do the data binding, I already tried this:

```
<clr-dropdown-menu *clrIfOpen name="rangeAge" [(ngModel)]="rangeAge">
```

but when i put the ngModel there the dropDown stops showing the options.

This is the link for the [dropdown clarity project][1]

[1]: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/dropdowns where i got the example

Comment: You are using the wrong component. The clarity dropdown isn't meant to be used like a select element. Here's what you want:
https://clarity.design/documentation/select

That documentation link is also outdated, the current one is located at:
https://v2.clarity.design/

Comment: let me check with my boss, they give the template using that hahaha @nullptr.t

Answer (score 0):

```
<clr-dropdown>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" clrDropdownTrigger>
            Is Active
            <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
        </button>
        <clr-dropdown-menu *clrIfOpen>
            <div *ngFor="let Item of Items" clrDropdownItem  (click)="onMnuClick(Item)">{{Item}}</div>
        </clr-dropdown-menu>
```

and in your code:

```
onMnuClick(item: any) {
   console.log(item);
}
```